# aptitude не хочет удалять пакеты

Tags: debian

Поставил на VPS Debian, добавил `testing`, `unstable` репозитории и как всегда установив `aptitude`  и апгрейднувшись с новых репозиториев начал через него удалять все не нужные мне пакеты но вдруг обнаружил что ничего не хочет удалиться, `aptitude` пишет что n пакетов будет сохранено, если есть пакеты которые зависят от пакетов которые я хочу удалить, а раньше просто все что зависело от удаляемых мною пакетов также удалялось, как убрать эту новую политику и вернуть старую чтоб по моему приказу всё удалялось?

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, вводимую вами команду и весь её вывод. предварительно установив английский язык сообщений: `$ export LC_ALL=C`

Comment: Ну так там GUI, вот приведу пример, стоит 3 пакета: vim, vim-tiny, vim-common. vim и vim-tiny зависят от vim-common, если я поставлю в очередь на удаление vim-common то мне aptitude скажет что пакет vim-common будет сохранен в текущем состоянии, а раньше просто все 3 пакета(vim, vim-tiny, vim-common) ставились в очередь на удаление.

Comment: *там GUI* — наверно, *tui*. так не пользуйтесь им: http://paste.debian.net/892049/

Comment: Ну да, tui. Если б я мог не пользоваться то не задавал здесь вопрос, а так мне удобно им пользоваться для массового удаления пакетов.

Comment: вероятно, вам имеет смысл написать сообщение об ошибке по этому поводу. программа `reportbug` из одноимённого пакета поможет вам в этом.